# Cannot Delete Key From Redis

Tags: redis

I'm trying to delete this key

`local::1:global:queries:/search/issues?version=1.9&amp;search=&amp;limit=20&amp;offset=0&amp;category=1152:count`

from my Redis database using the `DEL` command, but it will not delete. It just returns 0.

I'm able to delete other keys that are much simpler i.e. `local::1:global:categories:1152` without a problem.

I'm trying to remove this key using the NodeJS Redis library via `client.del(key)`

The value of the key is very simple. 
`[{"count":"20"}]`

Comment: can u share the value for the key that u mentioned?

Comment: While this is not the solution to my problem I was able to delete this using a delete by pattern function that involves using IORedis.

Comment: I've also replaced all the URL type characters with colons and then done a delete which works as well. For some reason Redis seems to not like something in that path.

Comment: I don't know Redis, but... Are you able to delete other keys containing an `&`? Are you sure you saved it with `&amp;` (not passing through XML/HTML machinery that converts it to `&`)? Are you sure the key has no spaces at the beginning or at the end?

Comment: Those are good suggestions @WalterTross. I will give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to quote the key, depending on how you are deleting it.

Via `redis-cli` in terminal:

```
del `local::1:global:queries:/search/issues?version=1.9&amp;search=&amp;limit=20&amp;offset=0&amp;category=1152:count`
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I tried this via the command line and via NodeJS and it didn't work in either.

Comment: Are you using the backtick (`) and not the single quote (') ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case matching pattern will work due to "/search/issues?version=1.9&amp;search=&amp;limit=20&amp;offset=0&amp;category=1152"

[image]

So you can run do it through Lua scripts   (redis 2.6.0^)

[here is more Information](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

```
EVAL "return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', KEYS[1])))"  1 local:*
```

Or using bash

```
redis-cli KEYS "local:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

Comment: From everything I've read using the KEYS command is not something you want to do in a production environment.

Comment: You are right @JamesParker. Its depend upon you how you create the  key